# Bootstrap Layout center container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and am trying to create the following layout without success.

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Logo row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="header">
                <img id="logoImage" src="#" height="67px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- QRCODE row-->
    <div class="row gradient qrCodeRow ">
        <div class="row" style="height: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="qrCode"><img src="#" height="300px" width="300px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="text qrText ">
                <p class="bigText"><strong>text</strong> text</p>
                <p>text</p>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container-fluid {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .v-center {
        position: relative;
        transform: translateY(50%);
    }

    .gradient {
        background: #1a5062; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1a5062, #0d2933); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#1a5062, #0d2933); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1a5062, #0d2933); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
        background: linear-gradient(#1a5062, #0d2933); /* Standard syntax */
    }

    .text {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    /* header */
    .header {
        height: 121px;
        padding: 0px 36px 0px 36px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    /* qrcode */
    .qrCodeRow {
        min-height:502px;
    }

    .qrCode {
        float: right;
    }

    .qrCode img {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;;
    }

    .qrText {
        height: 300px;
        padding-left: 45px;
        font-size: 24pt;
        font-family: "DIN Neuzeit Grotesk Std Light";
    }
```

I can not figure out how to make the middle part stay 1200px all the time until it has to resize. And I haven't even started thinking of how to make M1 go on top of M2.

Comment: [Click here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to read bootstrap solution your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. First I created a header that is empty and fullwidth. Next I created the main element with the container (of 1200px) in it. The container has a negative margin-top to pull it up. Inside this container you can find the 2 columns. Adding `col-xs-12` will make the column 100% width on xs-devices (extra small devices eq phones) and `col-md-4` will make this column only 4/12th width of the container on medium devices (desktop) adding these 2 classes together with some offset for the columns makes it responsive. Below you can see the code created in this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/04pBMcDCSu

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color: red;">
  <header style="height: 300px; background-color: white;">
  </header>
  <main>
    <!-- (1) -->
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: -100px; background-color: yellow;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" style="background-color: blue; height: 300px;">
          <h1>M1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2" style="background-color: green; height: 300px;">
          <h1>M2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- (2) -->
  </main>
</div>
```